# Return awk split array to a bash variable

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have a requirement to split a string on a multi-character delimiter and return the values into an array in Bash for further processing

IFS can take a single character delimiter.

```
a="2;AAAAA;BBBBB;1111_MultiCharDel_2;CCCC;DDDDDD;22222_MultiCharDel_2;EEEE;FFFFFFF;22222" 
awk'{split($0,ArrayDeltaMulDep,"_MultiCharDel_")}' <<< $a
```

The input string can have several substrings separated by the MultiCharDel delimiter.

How can i access this array ArrayDeltaMulDep fur further processing in Bash?

Comment: what about `awk '{split(...); print ArrayDeltaMulDep[3]}` <<< $a` for example.Else please clarify your Q with required example output. That is always a good thing to include ;-) .. Good luck.

Comment: Will it not just return the 4th element of the ArrayDeltaMulDep array? I need to get the full ArrayDeltaMulDep array for further processing in my code.

Comment: as I said, "Else please clarify your Q with required example output. ". Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example string, `a`, does not contain newlines.  If that is true in general, then:

```
a="2;AAAAA;BBBBB;1111_MultiCharDel_2;CCCC;DDDDDD;22222" 
readarray -t b <<< "${a//MultiCharDel/$'\n'}"
```

We can verify that this split the string properly using `declare -p` to show the value of `b`:

```
$ declare -p b
declare -a b=([0]="2;AAAAA;BBBBB;1111_" [1]="_2;CCCC;DDDDDD;22222")
```

How it works:

1. `readarray -t b`

   This reads lines from stdin and puts then in a bash array `b`.
2. `<<< "${a//MultiCharDel/$'\n'}"`

   `${a//MultiCharDel/$'\n'}` uses pattern substitution to replace `MultiCharDel` with a newline character.  `<<<` provides the result as stdin to the command `readarray`.

Hat tip: [Chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner)

### More general solution

A bash string will never contain a null character (hex 00).  Using GNU sed:

```
b=()
while read -d '' -r line
do
   b+=("$line")
done < <(sed 's/MultiCharDel/\x00/g; s/$/\x00/' <<<"$a")
```

This again creates an array with the desired splitting:

```
$ declare -p b
declare -a b=([0]="2;AAAAA;BBBBB;1111_" [1]="_2;CCCC;DDDDDD;22222")
```

Comment: Does this solution work even if there are several sub-strings separated by the MultiCharDel ??Ex the string a can also be a="2;AAAAA;BBBBB;1111_MultiCharDel_2;CCCC;DDDDDD;22222_MultiCharDel_2;EEEE;FFFFFFF;22222"

Comment: @NishantShrivastava In that string, there is only one occurrence of `MultiCharDel`.  I copy and pasted the string from your comment and, after the _second_ occurrence of `Multi`, but only the second occurrence, there are _two zero-width unicode characters_.  That prevents the second occurrence from being matched.

Comment: `readarray -t b <<< "${a//MultiCharDel/$'\n'}"` would be far better than an unquoted expansion inside parentheses.

Comment: @chepner That is a vastly superior approach!  Answer updated.

Comment: Sadly the version of bash that i am using does not support readarray

Comment: @NishantShrivastava You can use `while IFS= read -r line; do b+=("$line"); done <<< "${a//MultiCharDel/$'\n'}"` in its place.

Comment: @chepner . Thanks for the input.